# Application compatible with openssl giving error while compiled in visual studio 2005

Tags: c, visual-studio, openssl, wpa

I am trying to build wpa_supplicant which is referencing openssl header file x509v3.h on Visual studio 2005. while i am building compiler hitting x509v3.h header file and finding hell lot of errors. Can anybody please help me.

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(192) : error C2059: syntax error : '('

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(200) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(204) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(205) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(211) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GENERAL_NAME'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(212) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(231) : error C2059: syntax error : '('

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(232) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(249) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DIST_POINT_NAME'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(253) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(323) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GENERAL_NAME'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(326) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(358) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DIST_POINT_NAME'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(364) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(524) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(524) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(524) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

1>D:\Interworking\wpa_supplicant-1.0.tar\wpa_supplicant-1.0\wpa_supplicant-1.0\src\tls\x509v3.h(524) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: Have you read [the instructions for compiling on Windows](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob_plain;f=wpa_supplicant/README-Windows.txt)? Also please provide your full command sequence. Maybe this can help better isolate the problem.

Comment: Javex I have read. According that i have installed winpcap and openssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got reolved this happened due to #define of variable and strcuture variable.